# How can i get API-Response that includes localized data using json_expand?

Tags: localization, json, plugin-jsonexpand

My index.html endpoint in the templates folder looks like this:

```
    {% header "Content-Type: application/json" %}
    {% set basics = craft.entries.section('basics').find('') %}
    {{ basics | json_expand | raw  }}
```

I did enable the fields and put some localized strings inside,
still json returns this:

```
[
 {
"id": "261",
"enabled": "1",
"archived": "0",
"locale": "de",
"localeEnabled": "1",
"slug": "wimpern-richtig-tuschen",
"uri": null,
"dateCreated": {
  "date": "2015-11-26 12:08:01",
  "timezone_type": 3,
  "timezone": "UTC"
},
"dateUpdated": {
  "date": "2015-12-07 15:03:51",
  "timezone_type": 3,
  "timezone": "UTC"
},
"root": null,
"lft": null,
"rgt": null,
"level": null,
"sectionId": "7",
"typeId": "9",
"authorId": "153",
"postDate": {
  "date": "2015-11-26 12:08:00",
  "timezone_type": 3,
  "timezone": "UTC"
},
"expiryDate": null,
"parentId": null,
"revisionNotes": null,
"title": "Wimpern richtig tuschen",
"basics_text": "Wimpern richtig tuschen", (etc...)
```

is there a way to make an endpoint just for the english version, like basics_en ? Is there even any way to get the localized data using this method? The CMS is for a mobile-app, so i just need the raw data from the endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was pretty easy :)

```
{% header "Content-Type: application/json" %}
{% set basics = craft.entries.section('basics').locale('en').find('') %}
{{ basics | json_expand | raw  }}
```

all it needed was: `.locale('en')`